# AzureAD // Terraform Cycle Error Undefined

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to create a App Registration with Azuread Provider and use the applictionid output for a Configuration in my appservice. Everytime I plan, i got a Error Message. If i remove the Configuration Line, everything works fine.

I tried to put the App-Registration in a Module and work with the output but I got the same error.

Does anyone have an advise?

```
//Azure App Registration
  resource "azuread_application" "appregistration" {
  name                       = "${var.state}Site-${var.typ}-ar"
  reply_urls                 = ["https://${azurerm_app_service.appservice.default_site_hostname}/signin-callback"]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true
}
resource "azuread_application_password" "AppRegistrationPwd" {
  application_object_id = "${azuread_application.appregistration.id}"
  value                 = "SOMECODE"
  end_date              = "2020-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}
resource "azuread_service_principal" "serviceprincipal" {
  application_id                = "${azuread_application.appregistration.application_id}"
  app_role_assignment_required  = false
}
```

Appservice

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice" {
    name = "${var.state}-Site-${var.typ}-as"
    location = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.serviceplan.resource_group_name}"
    app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.serviceplan.id}"

    site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

    app_settings = {
    "AzureAd:ClientId"  = "${azuread_service_principal.serviceprincipal.application_id}"


  }



  }
```

Error:

```
Error: Cycle: module.devcentralhub.azuread_service_principal.serviceprincipal, module.devcentralhub.azurerm_app_service.appservice, module.devcentralhub.azuread_application.appregistration
```

Comment: I think I got it. The problem is "which" comes first. The Appservice need the ClientID and the Application Service need the primary URL from the appservice, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is right as your comment, the resource `azurerm_app_service` needs the `application_id` from the resource `azuread_service_principal` while the resource `azuread_service_principal` needs the app service name in the `reply_urls`, so it causes the cycle.

To break the cycle, you could specify `${azurerm_app_service.appservice.default_site_hostname}` via `${var.state}-Site-${var.typ}-as.azurewebsites.net` since usually both values are the same.

Change to `reply_urls   = ["https://${var.state}-Site-${var.typ}-as.azurewebsites.net/signin-callback"]` in your code.